# Does the find() method for a MongoCollection call a query?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have made a MongoCollection and a document containing keys and values I want to search by. When I call mongocollection.find(document), I cannot see any queries being made on mongostat. However, when I take the object that is returned from the find() method, and call first() on it (inherited by FindIterable from MongoIterable), a read query appears on mongostat. Can anyone explain to me how this works? Why does the find() method return a FindIterable which doesn't have query matches, but instead querying it for matches makes queries? I can't see any explanation for how the find() method and first() method work from the documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161042/is-finditerabledocument-load-all-documents

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The code to use find is something like this:

```
collection.find({key: 'value_to_compare'})
```

Comment: Hello, I can find something by doing collection.find(document). If I want to get the first result from this query, I can do collection.find(document).first(), which returns an object inside a document. My question is: why does collection.find(document) not make a query to the database, but calling first() on the output from collection.find(document) does?

Comment: You've tried to iterate over collection.find(document).first() results with a foreach loop, to see what it logs?

Comment: Yes, it generates more queries. dnickless posted this thread which has the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161042/is-finditerabledocument-load-all-documents